# What's the symbol ID of the symbol for type aliases in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ide

where is the symbol (label) representing a type in VS Code?
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking because you don't see that icon in the page you linked? If that's the case, check if your icons are coming from an icon theme extension by running with extensions disabled (`code --disable-extensions`)

Comment: @user
i just want the label name for type alias in vscode for customize the icon

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can't find it in [the reference page listing symbol icons](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels) is probably because you're using an icon theme. If you disable that theme, you'll see it as: [image]/[image] which is `symbol-variable` (odd, since it's a type alias and not really a variable, but I guess they're just reusing the same symbol icon for something else). You can even confirm this by opening the VS Code developer tools (`Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`) and selecting that icon to show it in the devtools' elements panel, where you'll see it has the attribute `class="outline-element-icon inline codicon codicon-symbol-variable"`.

Comment: yes i spoted `symbol-variable` , it for js variable declaration, var,let,const.
I also find one for `interface`, but it weird we dont have one for types !
So we can customise icon for interface, but not for type !
Type and interface should share same symbole no ?
Why it lack type customisation !?

Comment: @jon who do you think I am? :P go ask the VS Code maintainers. In any case, I have answered your query to the limits of my abilities.

Comment: they send me to stackoverflow !

Comment: @jon link please (to the discussion you are referring to). What did they send you here for? For your question about what the symbol ID is? Or the follow-up question you have now asked here about why type aliases use the "variable" symbol ID? I suspect the former and not the latter.

Comment: The first is a mechanics question. The second is a design decision question. The world (Stack Overflow) can observe the mechanics of the design of the designers, but it generally cannot _know_ the minds of the designers to understand why they made certain design decisions unless they already explain why publicly (and I cannot find any existing explanation by googling "`github vscode issues typescript type alias "symbol-variable"`")